# process multiple Reports in php

Tags: php, memory, report

I am trying to do a system that generates multiple Reports **Excel files**,

the process of generating one reports is about many calculations for multiple accounts in my DB, I want to ask if anyone has a technology that handles this issue to avoid any memory limit exceed. I wrote my code in  a very simple way (using for loop for ) but I always get this error:

`Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted`

please see a part of my code:

```
function generate() {

// call functions to create an excel files with all needed calculations
// each function return excel sheet to save it in the output file 
$objPHPExcel->addSheet($this->createIndexSheet(), 0);
$objPHPExcel->addSheet($this->createFanGrowthSheet(), 1);
$objPHPExcel->addSheet($this->createDemographicsActiveSheet(), 2);
$objPHPExcel->addSheet($this->createDemographicsLifetimeSheet(), 3);
$objPHPExcel->addSheet($this->createEngagementPerDaySheet(), 4);
$objPHPExcel->addSheet($this->createEngagementReachPerPostSheet(), 5);
$objPHPExcel->addSheet($this->createContentPerformanceSheet(), 6);
$objPHPExcel->addSheet($this->createDailyNumberofStoriesCreatedSheet(), 7);
$objPHPExcel->addSheet($this->createSentimentAnalysisSheet(), 8);

$file      = dirname(__FILE__).'/../ExcelFiles/Output/' . time() . '.xlsx';
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->setIncludeCharts(TRUE);
$objWriter->save($file);

}
```

Comment: There's not enough information here to recommend anything beyond raising the memory limit and hoping for the best.  :P  If you want something more useful, include something helpful.  Like the code.

Comment: If we could see the code, that'd be great.

Comment: i added a part of my code